# How to make array with string list

Tags: javascript

I have a generated list which is like this

> 196-1526, 85-651, 197-1519

I need the array like this. Each node has two part. I need only the first part of each node in one array.

> 196, 85, 197

I already have this code which generage 196

```
str.substr(0,str.indexOf('-'));
```

Comment: is the generated list an javascript array? or a string?

Comment: You are almost there... Loop over the elements in your list and assign array elements according to the equation you already have.

Comment: It is a string. Unfortunetly I donno how to loop over it.

Comment: You can use split to turn your string into an array and then proceed like Floris suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
'196-1526, 85-651, 197-1519'.replace(/-\d+(,|$)/g, '').split(/\s/)
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Working like charm. Thank you mate :)

Comment: Thank you my friend It was fantastic :)

Answer (score 2):

if it's an array

```
var myarray = ["196-1526", "85-651", "197-1519"];
var newarray = [];
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
  var mnode = myarray[i].split("-");
   newarray.push(mnode[0].trim());
}
```

and if it's a string

```
var myarray = "196-1526, 85-651, 197-1519".split(",");
var newarray = [];
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
  var mnode = myarray[i].split("-");
   newarray.push(mnode[0].trim());
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Dbbc8/

Answer (score 2):

If the input is a string you can use [**split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [**push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), similar to this:

```
var x = "196-1526, 85-651, 197-1519"
var y = x.split(',');

var myArray = [];

for(i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
    myArray.push(y[i].split('-')[0].trim());
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EPU4z/) - Using `split()` and `push()`

---

Answer (score 0):

try this code using split

```
var text='196-1526, 85-651, 197-1519';
    var splittedtext=text.split(',');
    var numbers=new Array(); 
    for(var i=0;i<splittedtext.length;i++)
    {
        var furthsplit=splittedtext[i].split('-');
        numbers[i]=furthsplit[0];
    }
    alert(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pairs = str.split(", ");
var values = [];

for (var i=0; i< pairs.length; i++) {
    values.push(pairs[i].substr(0, pairs[i].indexOf('-')));
}
```